# How to build Quick Action Bar like in Contacts application for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation

I am interested in doing my application similar to the contact apps where on click on the image pops up a small quick action menu(Not sure of the name). In that you get option to call them, email them or do similar activity. I too have a list view with a image in it. On click of the image I want to show a similar small action bar that will give quick links to users to navigate to my next activity. Please let me know how to do this. A quick sample will be good. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO GreenDroid is a full-featured UI framework, but if you just want the QuickAction in your apps, you can use this http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/
Just feel this way is simpler :D

Answer (score 1):

The GreenDroid QuickAction is what you are looking for I think https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

Comment: You are right. This is what I wanted. But as I am new to android I would like to know how reliable is this? I mean will this introduce any issues in my applications like any exceptions when using it?

Comment: GreenDroid is a really reliable library just as SherlockActionBar they are both great and useful